# ASP MVC Client validation and fluent helper

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, fluent

I build fluent helper for build a html form in ASP MVC.
But the client validation d'ont work in this context.
Please help me to understand why in my helper the "EditorFor" not add the client validation.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    var html = Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.UserName); // Good example client validation
    <input type="submit" value="ok" />
}

@FormHelpers.Form(Html.Form()
    .Title("Connection utilisateur")
    .Error("")
    .AddMessage("Entrez vos identifiant.")
    .AddRow(row => row
        .AddField(
            "Nom utilisateur",new EditItem()
            {
                Value = Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName),
                // Validation client is not added !
                Error = Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName),
            }
           ))
    .AddRow(row => row
        .AddField(
            "Mot de passe",
            Html.Edit(model => model.Password)))
    .AddRow(row => row
        .AddField(
            "Se souvenir<br/> de moi",
            Html.Edit(model => model.Souvenir)))
    .Build())
```

**My Builder methode :**

```
   public FormViewModelBuilder AddRow(Func<FormRowViewModelBuilder, FormRowViewModelBuilder> rowBuildFunc)
        {
            FormRowViewModelBuilder builderRow = new FormRowViewModelBuilder();
            FormRowViewModel row = rowBuildFunc(builderRow).FormRowViewModel;
            FormViewModel.AddRow(row);

            return this;
        }
public FormRowViewModelBuilder AddField(string title, EditItem value)
    {
        FormFieldViewModel info = new FormFieldViewModel();
        info.Title = title;
        info.EditItem = value; **// Validation is not added !**
        FormRowViewModel.Fields.Add(info);
        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution, but I dont understand MvcForm interact with generate client validation.
THe simple solution :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@FormHelpers.Form(Html.Form()
    .Title("Connection utilisateur")
    .Error("")
    .AddMessage("Entrez vos identifiant.")
    .AddRow(row => row
        .AddField(
            "Nom utilisateur",new EditItem()
            {
                Value = Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName),
                // Validation client is not added !
                Error = Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName),
            }
           ))
    .AddRow(row => row
        .AddField(
            "Mot de passe",
            Html.Edit(model => model.Password)))
    .AddRow(row => row
        .AddField(
            "Se souvenir<br/> de moi",
            Html.Edit(model => model.Souvenir)))
    .Build())
}
```

Or

```
//Contructor 
public FormViewModelBuilder(MvcForm mvcForm)
{
    this.FormViewModel.MvcForm = mvcForm;
}
// Builder methode, Must be called in last
public FormViewModel Build()
{
    this.FormViewModel.MvcForm.EndForm();
    return FormViewModel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

In your web.config file? Have you loaded mvc javascript files?

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tools.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Yes i have good script and web.config configurate. The problème is than fluent editor is not in MvcForm block.